# Include specific stylesheet for specific language?

Tags: theming, i18n-l10n

I have the following stylesheets:

```
stylesheets[all][] = AAA.css
stylesheets[all][] = BBB.css
stylesheets[all][] = CCC.css
stylesheets[all][] = chinese.css
```

AAA, BBB and CCC are fine. They should show for all languages. But I need english.css to ONLY show if the language code of the current page being viewed is:

```
cn-zh
tw-zh
```

The language code is retrieved from the i18n module:

```
$language = i18n_language();
$languageCode = $language->language;
```

How can I include this stylesheet for this case?

Answer (score 1):

So you will probably need to remove the style sheet from your info file and add it in a pre-processor.

I normally don't recommend using pre-processor functions but this is kind of the ideal exception to that rule. Checkout [template_preprocess_html](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7.x). In that hook you can pull the active language setting and conditionally add the language specific css file with [drupal_add_css](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7.x)

```
function mytheme_preprocess_html()
{
  // Don't remember the code for this but you can figure that out.
  $language = getLanguage()

  if ($language == 'chinese_traditional')
  {
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/chinese.css');
  }
}
```

If the get language function uses a database call it would be better to do this in a custom module. DB calls in the theme are pretty much always a bad idea. You would in that case use the same code in [hook_preprocess_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7.x). At least that is what I was always told to do.